# Android: my app memory over 300MB of ram just on idle

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, memory-leaks, android-memory

i noticed that my app uses alot of memory so i used the profiler and found that as soon as the app starts and splash screen appear the app get over 150+MB even on splash before opening main or anyother activity.

Update: i solved all memory leaks, yet my app still my app uses on my real phone nearly 300+ MB of ram just while browsing the MainActivity with recycleview.

LeakCanary and i keeps giving me error that this is a cause of memory leaks so anyone please tell me how to solve it >

[image: MainActivity]

if you clicked any recyclerview items:

[image: itemclicked]

[[image: LeakCanary]]

Activity Code:

```
public class WorkDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> imagesFromURL = new ArrayList<String>();
    ActivityWorkDetailsBinding binding;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityWorkDetailsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        String workUid_details = getIntent().getExtras().getString("UID_Details");
        String title = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
        String description = getIntent().getExtras().getString("description");
        String location = getIntent().getExtras().getString("location");
        String path = getIntent().getExtras().getString("path");


        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Work").child(path);
        databaseReference.child(workUid_details).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                binding.workDetailsTitle.setText(title);
                binding.workDetailsDescription.setText(description);
                binding.workDetailsLocation.setText(location);
                binding.getUIDDetails.setText(workUid_details);

                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.child("images").getChildren()) {
                    String value = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue());
                    imagesFromURL.add(value);
                    //Log.i("Value", String.valueOf(imagesFromURL));
                }
                initRecyclerView();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
    }

    private void initRecyclerView(){
        binding.workDetailsImage.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        binding.workDetailsImage.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        binding.workDetailsImage.setHasFixedSize(true);
        PrivateRecyclerAdapter adapter = new PrivateRecyclerAdapter(this, imagesFromURL);
        binding.workDetailsImage.setAdapter(adapter);
        binding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

       /* //Add Divider between recyclerView items
        DividerItemDecoration itemDecorator = new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.HORIZONTAL);
        binding.workDetailsImage.addItemDecoration(itemDecorator);

        final int radius = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.radius);
        final int dotsHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.dots_height);
        final int color = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.green);
        binding.workDetailsImage.addItemDecoration(new DotsIndicatorDecoration(radius, radius * 2, dotsHeight, color, color));
        binding.workDetailsImage.setOnFlingListener(null);
        new PagerSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(binding.workDetailsImage);*/
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        imagesFromURL = null;
        binding.workDetailsImage.setAdapter(null);
        binding.workDetailsTitle.setText(null);
        binding.workDetailsLocation.setText(null);
        binding.workDetailsDescription.setText(null);
        binding.getUIDDetails.setText(null);
        binding.workDetailsImage.setAdapter(null);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the above code is that you are registering value event listener as anonymous implementation. Which will hold the reference of the activity. And based on the LeakCanary stack trace your activity was in destroyed state but due to the listener the activity instance is not being able to be garbage collected and hence it is being leaked. What you need to do is add and remove the listener as below.

1. Create the instance of ValueEventListener and store it in variable

   ```
   ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
           binding.workDetailsTitle.setText(title);
           binding.workDetailsDescription.setText(description);
           binding.workDetailsLocation.setText(location);
           binding.getUIDDetails.setText(workUid_details);

           for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.child("images").getChildren()) {
               String value = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue());
               imagesFromURL.add(value);
               //Log.i("Value", String.valueOf(imagesFromURL));
           }
           initRecyclerView();
       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
       }
   });
   ```
2. Register it in the onStart method of your activity lifecycle using

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onStart() {
   databaseReference.child(workUid_details).addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
   }
   ```
3. Remove the listener in onStop method of your activity lifecycle using

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onStop() {
   databaseReference.child(workUid_details).removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
   }
   ```

Comment: i did same as you said but i didn't notice any performance boost, also my app ram usage jump to 150+ mb as soon as the splash screen appear ??, i even made an empty activity and made the app open it first yet the app still uses 90+MB

Comment: on the empty activity

Comment: @Mini that should not be the problem as there are lot of things which goes behind the scene. What you should be worried about is that once you close the activity the memory is removing everything around that activity and no memory leaks are detected by LeakCanary

Comment: If there are no memory leaks then Android will take care of clearing memory using GC

Comment: used leak canary and android profiler there is  no leaks anymore i solved them, yet memory usage is big

Comment: @Mini as I mentioned that is not a problem as whenever there will be memory shortage GC will remove the unused allocations. You can read more about memory management on Android and it will solve your doubts

Comment: @Mini you may also checkout android efficient data structures and try replacing them in your code and see if they are improving the consumption or not.

Comment: @Mini if this answer your question then please accept the answer